# How to make the type of a React prop be equal to whatever is passed to it in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a List component. This list component takes in 2 props:

1. items = an array of items
2. component = a react component

The List's job is to loop over the items and render each item in the given component

```
// List

interface Props {
    items: any[]
    component: any
}

export function List(props: Props) {
    return (
        <>
            {props.items.map((item: any) => (
                <props.component {...item} />
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Below we use the List component. We created an array of titles and bodys and a Card component to render each item in. This Card component requires a title and a body prop.

However, in the first element of our items array, the title is missing. How can I make Typescript show me an error in my code editor that the title is missing?

It's currently not doing that. I don't want the List component prop to be tied directly to the Card interface because I want the List to be able to accept different components like a MyLink component or a MyImage component, etc.

For example if we passed in a MyLink component, then the href prop would be required.

If we passed in a MyImage then the src prop would be required.

-

```
// App
import { List } from '@/components/List'
import { Card } from '@/components/Card'

const items = [
    {
      body: 'body'
    },
    {
      title: 'my title2', 
      body: 'body2'
    }
    {
      title: 'my title3', 
      body: 'body3'
    }
]

export function Home() {
    return (
         <List items={items} component={Card}></List>    
    )
}
```

- 

```
// Card
interface Props {
    title: string
    body: string
}

export function Card(props: Props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.title}</h1>
            <h1>{props.body}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Use of **any** sounds justified here (rather than implementing a pseudo-**any** which is part of the question). The point at which *real* type checking occurs (according to the question) is when **props.component** is used in the `return` statement. But, isn't type checking at this point the responsibility of the **author** of props.component? If this component were not written in Typescript, wouldn't you write a Typescript declaration file (*.d.ts) for it? It would be this declaration file that would trigger the desired warnings or errors. Am I missing some context?

Answer (score 0):

There might be better ways to do it, but here is one way that should work.

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface CardProps {
    title: string
    body: string
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({
  title,
  body
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <h1>{body}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

// P = component props, C = the component, I = any type that extends P (component props).
interface ListProps<P = any, C extends React.ComponentType<P> = any, I extends React.ComponentProps<C> = any> {
    items: I[]
    component: C
}

// can't use React.FC typing here as we need the generics.
const List = <P = any, C extends React.ComponentType<P> = any, I extends React.ComponentProps<C> = any>({
  items,
  component: Component
}: ListProps<P, C, I>) => {

    return (
        <>
            {items.map((item: any) => (
                <Component {...item} />
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

const items = [
    {
      body: 'body'
    },
    {
      title: 'my title2', 
      body: 'body2'
    },
    {
      title: 'my title3', 
      body: 'body3'
    }
]

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    return (
         <List items={items} component={Card}></List>    
    )
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdwAdjFlAXlnAMLJQAmABWJh0AbzpwpcGMBgAbLAC44qGFGYBzSdIBGEfgE8VajU20BfBrghM1PPvxXY8MAHQAxbgB5eA4RCiAHxwALxwABQSUrIKWAA0OvpGdBYAlGEh0dKUMACuUEyROtLS3vzAAG5BJaV13gAWAIxBYrGKFt4A9M01df1wjS1iyYadPS21pd0V1bVpqQxdXXCCYXA24LZYLHBgIqjxPOswDVybkEw7MEcAkuvITIYyhmBcp8jwWAAerEz86DWEQu212%200CqDSbkYLDYHFwXAAMsA1AFRN41uFHoYjtw4D8-gDMFR3NwSJdrgAVV5YDEhLFPO74347IkufBuMlbK4sNGoXz0lBPLK1ORYECoFS3ADaAF1aiCeTAVNxFnRlhtHmR4HlUFx2e4vC8wFo4GdKCh0AB3LhXLD8GRnOCaHZsYC4VDQmx2eDI%20zhDEPRnHAms9AGznk0EwalvOlBnFwe6h-7hkmR7nXPkChNBKI6MUSxJSRXXFVRpWpFR%20mDZwS4u5BDKhEW1XIFIoRKZlPoDUpiQuekDIMARCKFlTY5shLt9vu%20CvXOBiNyrwsWOBdXtzuBpNJWedb%20Zq732QfraW1bKlUYqMijMi1CzF6TX6TtZTkEDPD8AJjIRzdre5CjP%20T4vlIb4xHIih3t%20MgwVgADMAFwEBBjGCBGEoU%20dDynQp7wAAEiQn4Rka4QRNOy5tlg%20SFMUc7eDWcCDqEA6sBKG6liw7F%20PwFhBN0NYhNIx4WEAA)